# What are the Advantages of Mainnet over Testnet?

Tags: blockchain, testnet

In recent days most of the ICO's starting with test net then developing their own block with mainnet. I don't know why they are doing this. What are the reasons behind this starting with testnet and switching to mainnet?

Comment: Testnet coins do not have any value. So it can be used for extensive testing of vulnerabilities and bugs. If any bugs exists and coins are lost, they are just testnet coins without any value. If the same happens on mainnet, you actually lose monetary value.

Comment: @UgamKamat: That sounds like a great start of an answer.